# Loading views with mvc: Php failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I want to make a controller with a method that loads my views dynamically.
The part where it goes wrong is that my controller doesn't seem to recognise my path where it should take my views from.. it gives an error with the message "

```
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening './views/home/index.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\stefv\SCHOOL\GENT\NMD\WEBDEV\webdev1-examen\webdev1-examen\App\Controllers\PageController.php 
on line 10
```

I have no clue because I tried every path and can't seem to fix it..
Here is my code:

My app.php:

```
<?php

require '../config/config.php';

require '../App/Models/dbModel.php';
require '../App/Models/Course.php';
require '../App/Models/Tag.php';

require '../App/Controllers/PageController.php';
require '../App/Controllers/HomeController.php';
require '../App/Controllers/CourseController.php';
require '../App/Controllers/TagController.php';
```

My Index.php:

```
<?php 
require './app.php';

$route = str_replace('/views/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$route = explode('/', $route);

$controller = (isset($route[0]) && $route[0] != '') ? $route[0] : 'Home';
$method = (isset($route[1]) && $route[1] != '') ? $route[1] : 'index';
$arg = $route[2] ?? '';

$controller_name = ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';

require_once "../App/Controllers/$controller_name.php";

$controller = new $controller_name();
$controller->{$method}($arg);
```

My Pagecontroller:

```
<?php

class PageController {

    protected function loadView($view, $params = [])  
    {
        extract($params);

        ob_start();
        include './views/'.$view. '.php';
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }

}
```

My HomeController:

```
<?php 

class HomeController extends PageController {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->loadView('home/index');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        $tags = new Tag();
        $tags = Tag::getAll();
        print_r($tags);
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't shared any file called `views/home/index.php`, so the error message sounds pretty legit to me. What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you explain how? Because in my pagecontroller I'm setting up a dynamic page renderer. So it takes the name of the view from the method in the homecontroller and the pagecontroller looks for the view that matches the name

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? If you wrote code that requires specific files to exist, but these files do not exist (as the error message indicates), **creating** such a file should be the obvious way to go?

Comment: oh wait, I can explain. the ../index.php is actually a method from the homecontroller to render my homepage. So home/index.php is no actual file